# Can't access a variable inside a jquery plugin as option/parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, variables, scope

i am having an issue in accessing a var into a jquery plugin option, here is my code:

```
        $.get("/dev/esag/upcomingevent", function (data) {

        var DateOfEvent = JSON.stringify(data);

        $(".countdown").jCounter({
            date: DateOfEvent, // '17 August 2018 12:00:00'
            fallback: function() { console.log("count finished!") }
        });

    });
```

i am receiving data through this request and have verified in console.log and i can access the DateOfEvent outside of the jCounter() but inside as a paremeter i am not getting anything.So when i put static string it works but when i use DateOfEvent variable it does not work.

Thanks

Comment: you need to include a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), without that, your guess is as good as ours.

Comment: Ahhhh!!! just sorted .... i had to use JSON.parse(data) instead of JSON.stringify(data) i found double quotes in console log around DateOfEvent  upon investigation. So Thanks Aniket Sahrawat (for giving me hint) and "i wrestled ..." for having look.